# Coin flipping: $4$ players $3$ flips - whose result is more probable and what's the probability?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider $4$ players $A,B,C,D$. Every player is assigned by an ordered triple of test results (of coin flipping), where $n$ stands for number and $h$ for head:

$$A:nnh,\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }B:nhh,\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }C:hhn,\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }D:hnn$$

A referee executes a sequence of coin flipping (where the coin is fair, e.g. $P(n)=P(h)=\frac{1}{2}).$

$2$ players play against each other and you are the winner if your triple occurs first in the sequence of the coin flipping.

What's probability that

(i) $A$ wins against $D$

(ii) $D$ wins against $C$

---

I'm very confused and think it's all just $50$%.. :p

Going a bit deeper into it though, we have in total $2^3=8$ possibilities:

$$\left\{nnh,nhn,hnn,nnn,hhn,hnh,nhh,hhh\right\}$$

After writing all possibilities, I even believe more that $\frac{1}{2}$ is the correct answer for both (i), (ii). Because every combination occurs exactly once and we have a total of $8$ combinations.. But it shouldn't be that easy and I'm most likely missing something.

But what is it? :o

Comment: This is unfortunately a non-transitive game.  There is a youtube video about this specific game that I might be able to find in a bit on either James Grime's channel (singing banana) or on Numberphile.  The probabilities will *not* simply be 50% each.  This can be described using the language of markov processes.  Notice for example that if one person was trying to get `hhh` and a different person was trying to get `nhh` that the *only* way that the first person wins if the first three flips are `hhh` because otherwise if more than four flips are used...

Comment: ...then the first occurrence of `hhh` has an `n` just before it, `...nhhh` and so the win actually goes to the second player.  Similarly, other shenanigans occur for your specific players and their strategies.  [The video I was referring to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sa9jLWKrX0c) (*by jame's grime on the numberphile channel, instead of on his personal channel*).

Comment: @cnmesr, your analysis applies if we throw three coins only. If that's the case, no player would have an edge against each other. Think about what happens when the $4$th coin is thrown.

Comment: I think the answer is 1/2 too as it is equally likely for A to win against D as is D to win against A.

Comment: @prog_SAHIL it is not.  Consider what situations $A$ wins against $D$.  If there are only three flips total, then the flips were `nnh`.  If there were four flips total and `A` wins, then it must have been `nnnh` and in particular could *not* have been `hnnh` because that would have been a win for $D$.  In general, the only way that $A$ wins is if the sequence of coins was `nnnn...nnnnh` for some number of `n`'s to begin with.  As long as at least one of the first two flips was an `h` instead, then $D$ is *guaranteed* to win before $A$ and if both of first two flips were `n` then $A$ wins.

Comment: @JMoravitz oh yes. thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling important information from comments so the question can have an answer:

$A$ will beat $D$ *if and only if* both of the first two flips were `n`'s.

To see this, suppose that the first two flips were `n`'s and consider the first occurrence of `h`.  Then it looks like `nn...nnnnnh` for some number of `n`'s to begin with.  In particular `hnn` cannot occur in this above sequence before `nnh` because we stated that the `h` pictured above is the *first* `h`.

Now, suppose instead that at least one of the first two flips were `h` and consider the first occurrence of `nn`.  Then it looks like `.h....hnn` for some number of `h`'s and possibly single `n`'s in the middle as well.  In particular, notice that the letter preceding the first occurrence of `nn` must be an `h`, else it was not the first occurrence of `nn` and notice that `nnh` cannot appear in the above before `hnn` because that would have required an earlier occurrence of `nn` than the one pictured which was stated to be the first.

So, we have successfully redescribed the problem of calculating the chance that $A$ beats $D$ as the problem of calculating the chance that both of the first two flips are `n`'s.  This occurs with probability $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$, so $A$ beats $D$ with probability $\frac{1}{4}$ and $D$ beats $A$ with probability $\frac{3}{4}$.

Similar observations can be made when comparing the likelihood of $D$ winning against $C$, though the probability will be different.

A perhaps surprising observation is that $A$ is favored to win against $B$.  $B$ is favored to win against $C$.  $C$ is favored to win against $D$.  And $D$ is favored to win against $A$.  The game is what we call "non-transitive" much like how rock-paper-scissors works.

For more information on this problem and its generalizations, check out [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sa9jLWKrX0c) by James Grime or the [wikipedia article on Penney's Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penney%27s_game).